# uiBarButtonItem frame in popover best alternative

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uipopovercontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have dragged+dropped a barButtonItem on Story board and have been using this popover code but

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.barButonItem.frame 
inView:self.view
permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

barButtonItem.frame does not work as no frame property is available .

What is the best aleternative to get it working perfectly ?
 Thanks in Advance.

Currently I am using this code :  I am using this method :

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender event:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *viewt = [[UIView alloc] init]; 

    for(UITouch* touch in [event allTouches] ) 
    {
      if( [touch phase] == UITouchPhaseEnded ) 
      { 
         viewt = [touch view]; 
      }
    }
}
```

`self.barButtonItem.frame` will become `viewt.frame` .

Its working for now . Is it correct ?

```
//create a popover controller with my DatePickerViewController in it


UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; //ViewController

UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];   //view
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];//Date picker
datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320, 216);
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker setMinuteInterval:5];
[datePicker setTag:10];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(Result) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[popoverView addSubview:datePicker];

popoverContent.view = popoverView;
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
popoverController.delegate=self;



[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.barButtonItem.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use `[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];` directly.